# LWJGL2, OpenGL framebuffer only rendering a partial flat-shaded section of the scene

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, framebuffer

I am trying to simply render the scene to a framebuffer object and then back to the screen. The issue is that the framebuffer ends up rendering out what looks to be the lower left quadrant of the scene with only flat shading. When I render normally without the FBO all the shading is normal and the whole scene is rendered. I don't understand why this isn't what the FBO gets.

I am rendering to a quad that fits the screen and glViewport is always set to the display width.

Something to note is that it looks suspiciously like it's rendering from the position of the first entity.

No FBO:

[image]

With FBO:

[image]

FBO class:

```
public class FrameBufferObject
{
    private int frameBuffer;

    private int colourBuffer;
    private int depthBuffer;

    private int colourTexture;
    private int depthTexture;

    private int colourWidth;
    private int colourHeight;

    private int depthWidth;
    private int depthHeight;

    private int depthType;

    public static final int NONE = 0;
    public static final int DEPTH_TEXTURE = 1;
    public static final int DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER = 2;

    public FrameBufferObject(int textureWidth, int textureHeight, int depthWidth, int depthHeight, int depthBufferType)
    {
        this.colourWidth = textureWidth;
        this.colourHeight = textureHeight;
        this.depthWidth = depthWidth;
        this.depthHeight = depthHeight;
        this.depthType = depthBufferType;

        initialiseFrameBuffer(depthBufferType);
    }

    public FrameBufferObject(int width, int height, int depthBufferType)
    {
        this.colourWidth = width;
        this.colourHeight = height;
        this.depthWidth = width;
        this.depthHeight = height;
        this.depthType = depthBufferType;

        initialiseFrameBuffer(depthBufferType);
    }

    private void initialiseFrameBuffer(int type)
    {
        frameBuffer = glGenFramebuffers();
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

        colourTexture = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colourTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, colourWidth, colourHeight,
                0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer) null);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                colourTexture, 0);

        if (type == DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER) {
            depthBuffer = glGenRenderbuffers();
            glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
            glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, depthWidth, depthHeight);
            glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
        }
        else if (type == DEPTH_TEXTURE)
        {
            depthTexture = glGenTextures();
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, depthWidth, depthHeight,
                    0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                    depthTexture, 0);
        }

        unbindFrameBuffer();
    }

    public void bindFrameBuffer()
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        glViewport(0, 0, colourWidth, colourHeight);
    }

    public void unbindFrameBuffer()
    {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
    }

    public void cleanUp()
    {
        glDeleteFramebuffers(frameBuffer);
        glDeleteTextures(colourTexture);
        glDeleteTextures(depthTexture);
        glDeleteRenderbuffers(depthBuffer);
        glDeleteRenderbuffers(colourBuffer);
    }

    public int getColourTexture() {
        return colourTexture;
    }

    public int getDepthBuffer() {
        return depthBuffer;
    }
}
```

Renderer:

```
    public EntityRenderer(StaticShader staticShader)
    {
        this.staticShader = staticShader;
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glEnable(GL_BACK);
        
        projectionMatrix = MatrixUtils.projectionMatrix();

        this.staticShader.start();
        this.staticShader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
        this.staticShader.stop();
    }

    public void prepare() {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    private void prepareRenderInstance(Transform transform) {
        Matrix4f matrix = MatrixUtils.transformationMatrix(transform);
        staticShader.loadTransformationMatrix(matrix);
    }

    private void unbindMesh() {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    private Map<StaticMesh, List<RawModel>> getMeshes()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Collection<Entity> entities = World.getEntities().values();

        for (Entity entity : entities)
        {
            StaticMesh mesh = 
(entity.getComponent(StaticMeshComponent.class)).getMesh();

            prepareMesh(mesh);

            prepareRenderInstance(entity.getTransform());
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getModel().getVertexCount(), 
GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            unbindMesh();
        }

    private void prepareMesh(StaticMesh mesh)
    {
        RawModel rawModel = mesh.getModel();
        Material material = mesh.getMaterials().get(0);

        glBindVertexArray(rawModel.getVaoID());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        staticShader.loadSpecular(10f, 1f);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, material.getTexture().getId());
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, rawModel.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanUp()
    {
        staticShader.cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Main render method where I bind the framebuffer:

```
    public void render()
    {
        gameBuffer.bindFrameBuffer();

        List<Light> lights = World.getLights();

        entityRenderer.prepare();

        staticShader.start();
        staticShader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
        staticShader.loadLights(lights);

        entityRenderer.render();

        staticShader.stop();

        gameBuffer.unbindFrameBuffer();

        WidgetManager.swap(gameBuffer.getColourTexture());
        widgetRenderer.render();
    }
```

Shader program base class:

```
public abstract class GenericShader
{
    private static int programID;
    private static int vertexShaderID;
    private static int fragmentShaderID;

    private static FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

    public GenericShader(String vertexFile, String fragmentFile)
    {
        this.vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile, 35633);
        this.fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile, 35632);
        this.programID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        bindAttributes();
        glLinkProgram(programID);
        glValidateProgram(programID);
        getAllUniformLocations();
    }

    public void start() {
        glUseProgram(programID);
    }

    public void stop() {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        stop();
        glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
        glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
        glDeleteProgram(programID);
    }

    protected abstract void getAllUniformLocations();

    protected int getUniformLocation(String uniformName) {
        return glGetUniformLocation(programID, uniformName);
    }

    protected void loadBoolean(int location, boolean value) {
        glUniform1f(location, value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    protected void loadFloat(int location, float value) {
        glUniform1f(location, value);
    }

    protected void loadVector3D(int location, Vector3f vec) {
        glUniform3f(location, vec.x, vec.y, vec.z);
    }

    protected void loadMatrix(int location, Matrix4f matrix)
     {
        matrix.store(matrixBuffer);
        matrixBuffer.flip();
        glUniformMatrix4(location, false, matrixBuffer);
    }

    protected abstract void bindAttributes();

    protected void bindAttribute(int attribute, String variableName) {
        glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, variableName);
    }

    private static int loadShader(String file, int type) {
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException var5) {
            var5.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Could not read shader.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        int shaderID = glCreateShader(type);
        glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
        glCompileShader(shaderID);
        if (glGetShaderi(shaderID, 35713) == 0) {
            System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
            System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return shaderID;
    }
}
```

Static shader:

```
    public StaticShader()
    {
        super(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindAttributes()
    {
        super.bindAttribute(0, "position");
        super.bindAttribute(1, "textureCoordinates");
        super.bindAttribute(2, "normals");
    }

    @Override
    protected void getAllUniformLocations()
    {
        location_transformationMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
        location_projectionMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
        location_viewMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("viewMatrix");
        location_shineDamper = super.getUniformLocation("shineDamper");
        location_reflectivity = super.getUniformLocation("reflectivity");
        location_useFakeLighting = super.getUniformLocation("useFakeLighting");
        location_skyColour = super.getUniformLocation("skyColour");
        location_density = super.getUniformLocation("density");
        location_gradient = super.getUniformLocation("gradient");
        location_atlasRows = super.getUniformLocation("atlasRows");
        location_offset = super.getUniformLocation("offset");

        //location_lightPositions = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];
        //location_lightColours = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];
        //location_attenuations = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];

        //for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
        //{
            location_lightPosition = super.getUniformLocation("lightPosition");//s[" + i + "]");
            location_lightColour = super.getUniformLocation("lightColour");//s[" + i + "]");
            //location_attenuation = super.getUniformLocation("attenuations[" + i + "]");
        //}
    }

    public void loadLights(List<Light> lights)
    {
        super.loadVector3D(location_lightPosition, lights.get(0).getTransform().position);
        super.loadVector3D(location_lightColour, lights.get(0).getColour());
    }

    public void loadSpecular(float shineDamper, float reflectivity) {
        super.loadFloat(location_shineDamper, shineDamper);
        super.loadFloat(location_reflectivity, reflectivity);
    }

    public void loadTransformationMatrix(Matrix4f matrix)
    {
        super.loadMatrix(location_transformationMatrix, matrix);
    }

    public void loadProjectionMatrix(Matrix4f matrix)
    {
        super.loadMatrix(location_projectionMatrix, matrix);
    }

    public void loadViewMatrix(Camera camera)
    {
        Matrix4f viewMatrix = MatrixUtils.createViewMatrix(camera);
        super.loadMatrix(location_viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    }
```

Comment: For OpenGL questions, screenshots always help. What is it supposed to look like? What does it actually look like?

Comment: @user253751 Updated.

Comment: Are you clearing the depth and color buffer bit every time you call bindFrameBuffer?

Comment: @Syncit I am doing glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) before rendering the meshes. I tried adding it when calling bindFrameBuffer with no effect.

Comment: I don't spot anything wrong with the framebuffer code, so please add the drawing code as well

Comment: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32 - this could be a problem, if opengl context was initialized with 16 or 24 bit depth buffer. Did you tried GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT?

Comment: Show us the code where you call bindFrameBuffer in your renderer

Comment: @Syncit Added more details.

Comment: @МатвейВислоух Just tried what you suggested and nothing changed. The PixelFormat says it's 8bit if that's what you mean about the context.

Comment: glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTextureId,0);  not the glFramebufferTexture.

Comment: @МатвейВислоух Still the same unfortunately.

Comment: There a lot of working examples, just take one: [link](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers)

Comment: You said you were rendering the framebuffer to an full screen quad but it looks like you main renderer is just rendering to the frameBuffer and stops there. Where is the code where you bind your framebuffer texture to that quad and render it? Or did u use glBlitFrameBuffer somewhere else?

Comment: @Syncit I have a post process class that just renders to a quad, it renders textures fine. I went through the whole project with glGetError and I seem to be getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION when calling glUniformMatrix4 with the view matrix so maybe that is part of it. Anyway I have just decided to take a working example and insert my engine code in piece by piece until it breaks haha.